# Migration not working

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a project that uses .net core 2.0 with EntityFrameworkCore, Docker and SQL Server.

I can't get migrations to work. When I try `Add-Migration InitialCreate` I get the following error:

> Startup project 'docker-compose' is a Docker project. Select an
>   ASP.NET Core Web Application as your startup project and try again.

I don't even have a asp.net web application but just a .net core console program. How do I enable migrations?

If I change the startup project to the console application I get:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an
>   implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory'
>   to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
>   for additional patterns supported at design time.

Comment: Did you try adding an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`?

Comment: I indeed did. But thanks to your comment I looked over it again and found a bug... It's working now! Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but what was your solution? I'm having the same problem and I'm sure it would also be useful for others to know

Answer (score 8):

The answer to the error `Startup project 'docker-compose' is a Docker project. Select an ASP.NET Core Web Application as your startup project and try again.` Was to right click my actual code project in VisualStudio and click Set as Startup Project.

The solution file had marked the docker-compose project as the default project.

Answer (score 0):

`Add-Migration` has optional parameters `-StartupProject` and `-Project`.

These allow you to specify alternatives to the solutions configured Startup Project and the currently selected project in Package Manager/Console

If the project you want the migrations to be created in is not actually your Startup project then using these parameters means you do not have to constantly change your solutions configuration every time you want to run a migration.

So the command would look like:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -StartupProject MyProjectName -Project MyProjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cause to:

> Startup project 'docker-compose' is a Docker project. Select an
> ASP.NET Core Web Application as your startup project and try again.

can also be that your context is missing expected constructor signatures. You need those:

```
public SomeContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}

public SomeContext()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For

> Startup project 'docker-compose' is a Docker project. Select an ASP.NET Core Web Application as your startup project and try again.

There are two possible solutions:

1. In Visual Studio, right click on the project that has the DbContext
   and **mark as a startup project**
2. Specify in the Add-Migration command the  **-StartupProject** example:

   `Add-Migration Initialize -StartupProject ProjectName`

For:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.

**In-depth check the link provided in the exception: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 :**

But for your your case: **.NET Console app**
I would suggest in building a **Design-time factory class** for your DBContext:

Example from the provided link (they use sqlLite as a provider, but you can specify whatever provider you want, while also having the correct Nuget packages installed):

```
public class BloggingContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```